# Grails one-to-one mapping that shares an ID

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I have the following domain classes in Grails **2.3.11**. They are mapping to legacy database tables that can't be changed. Both classes share an id called `pidm`:

```
class Person {
    Long pidm
    String firstName
    String middleName
    Bio bio

    static mapping = {
        id name: 'pidm', generator: 'assigned'
        bio column: 'pidm'
    }
}

class Bio {
    Long pidm
    String ssn
    String gender
    Date birthDate

    static mapping = {
        id name: 'pidm', generator: 'assigned'
    }
}
```

There is no separate `person_id` column in the `Bio` table or anything like that. There should be a one-to-one mapping via `pidm`.

Currently the only way I can get this to work is to add `updateable: false, insertable: false` to `bio` in the `mapping` block. What if I want to update and/or insert a Bio instance? Is there a better way for me to do this and share the `pidm` column as the id for the Person class *AND* as a reference to Bio?

Comment: Is the generator really 'assigned' and primary key is Number? Is there no sequence available for these tables in legacy database?

Comment: There is, but my apps won't create new Person or Bio objects. Separate systems handle the creation of entries in these tables.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to make the following changes in your Bio class and related mappings :

- Use a **foreign ID generator**.
- Introduce a hasOne/belongTo bi-directional relationship
- You also need to make sure that any linked element property is not insertable or updatable.

**For a concrete example**

http://blog.swwomm.com/2011/09/grails-foreign-id-generator.html

**Other references**

- http://grails.org/doc/2.3.9/ref/Database%20Mapping/insertable.html
- http://grails.org/doc/2.3.9/ref/Database%20Mapping/updateable.html
- http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work for me even in a grails project that has nothing else in it.

Comment: @GailTerman, you'll need to be more specific about what you tried with ideally some code and stack trace. I recall some "minor" issues on my end, while trying to make it work within tight deadlines. I didn't blindly copy/paste the code from the referenced article.